# Android code to pure java

Tags: java, android

I want to know which is the tag used in pure java instead of the following codes in android

```
Looper
ViewerApp
inputMgr
getWindowToken()
InputMethodManager
```

For example in pure java we use JOptionPane instead of toast in android.
What is the use of ViewerApp in android and also looper in android.
Please help....

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If you are asking for the equivalent J2SE classes for the Android variant, it would pay to link to the JavaDocs for each Android class e.g. [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html).

Answer (score 1):

Some of these things don't have equivalents in Java. `InputMethodManager` is an Android-specific way of dealing with the on screen keyboard. I believe `inputMgr` is just a reference to `InputMethodManager`, but you don't give enough info to make that clear. This question can't really be answered the way you want simply because there isn't a one to one mapping of Android constructs to Java constructs. Android is meant for mobile devices with touch screens, while Java (loosely speaking) is not.